# Z-projection of z-stack using .czi files

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a z-projection using .czi files in R. Nonetheless, the file I'm getting does not have the same color as in the .czi file (for instance the GFP fluorescence was being shown as yellow and in the figure made by the R script it is white).

Does anybody know how to use the same color as in the .czi file?

Thank you

```
library(readCzi)
library(tiff)

## Input file
input_file <- "file.czi"

## 1. Read CZI file and store as array -------------------------------------
image_data <- readCzi(input_file = input_file)

## 2. Read metadata of CZI file and save as CSV ----------------------------
##    (in German and English format)
df_metadata <- readCziMetadata(input_file = input_file,
                               save_metadata = TRUE)

file_path_en <- file.path(dirname(input_file), "output",
                          paste0(gsub("\\.czi", "", basename(input_file)),
                                 "_df_metadata_en.csv"))

dir.create(path = file.path(dirname(input_file), "output"),
           showWarnings = FALSE)
readr::write_csv(x = df_metadata, file = file_path_en)

## 3. Create sum Z-projection for one channel -------------------------------
# Select channel index (adjust as needed)
channel_index <- 3

# Select data for the specified channel
channel_data <- image_data[,,channel_index,]

# Create sum Z-projection for the selected channel
sum_projection <- apply(channel_data, c(1, 2), sum)

## 4. Define TIFF path ------------------------------------------------------
# Define the TIFF path
tiff_path <- file.path(dirname(input_file), "output",
                       paste0(gsub("\\.czi", "", basename(input_file)),
                              "_channel_", channel_index, "_sum_projection.tiff"))

# Check if the file already exists
if (file.exists(tiff_path)) {
  # Append sequential number until a unique filename is found
  i <- 1
  repeat {
    # Construct the new filename
    new_tiff_path <- gsub("\\.tiff$", paste0("_", i, ".tiff"), tiff_path)
    # Check if the new filename exists
    if (!file.exists(new_tiff_path)) {
      tiff_path <- new_tiff_path
      break
    }
    i <- i + 1
  }
}

# Normalize sum_projection to the range [0, 1]
min_val <- min(sum_projection)
max_val <- max(sum_projection)
sum_projection_normalized <- (sum_projection - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)

## Map intensity values to green color --------------------------------------
# Map intensity values to green color (0 = black, 1 = green)
green_color_mapping <- sum_projection_normalized

## Write sum projection with green color to TIFF file -----------------------
# Write sum projection with green color to TIFF file
tiff::writeTIFF(green_color_mapping, tiff_path)
```